# PHP Complete sub array with the same number of elements

Tags: php, arrays, sub-array

I have an array as following.

```
Array ( 
    [A] => Array ( 
             [y] => 2014-11-26 
             [x] => 1 
             [zzz] => 2 
             [ww] => 1 ) 
    [B] => Array ( 
             [y] => 2014-11-27 
             [zzz] => 2 ) 
    [C] => Array ( 
             [y] => 2014-11-29 
             [ww] => 2 ) 
 )
```

The sub array 'A' has four elements while other sub arrays have only two elements. I would like to fill those other sub array with the same elements of array A with the value 0 so that I get a new array as following.

```
Array ( 
    [A] => Array ( 
             [y] => 2014-11-26 
             [x] => 1 
             [zzz] => 2 
             [ww] => 1 ) 
    [B] => Array ( 
             [y] => 2014-11-27 
             [x] => 0
             [zzz] => 2 
             [ww] => 0 ) 
    [C] => Array ( 
             [y] => 2014-11-29 
             [x] => 0
             [zzz] => 0 
             [ww] => 2 ) 
 )
```

Below is my algorithme. Because I am a junior developer I am looking for a better algorithme to learn more.

```
    $allArrayKey = array_keys($array); 

    $mostElement[0] = 0;
    foreach($allArrayKey as $value) {

        if($mostElement[0] < count($array[$value])) {
            $mostElement[0] = count($array[$value]);
        }

    }

    foreach($allArrayKey as $arr) {           
        if(count($array[$arr]) < $mostElement[0]) {
            foreach ($allArrayKey as $xx) {
                if(!array_key_exists($xx, $array[$arr])) {
                    $array[$arr][$xx] = '0';
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

How can I do that in PHP?

Comment: get all keys from array A, loop trough main array, check if all keys exists, if not add

Comment: It is customary to Google around, read the docs, have a try at it and when your code doesn't work to post it here and ask for help. Not to ask "please code this for me"

Comment: @Mawg: I could solve it with a sloppy algorithme because I am a junior developer. I asked this question to look for a better algorithme to gain a better knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Create a dummy array `any_key => 0` and add it to each subarray:

```
$a = array(
    array('x' => 1, 'y' => 2, 'z' => 3, 'w' => 4),
    array('x' => 11, 'y' => 22, ),
    array('x' => 111, 'y' => 222),
);

$dummy = array_combine(
    array_keys($a[0]),
    array_fill(0, count($a[0]), 0)
);

foreach($a as &$v)
    $v += $dummy;

print_r($a);
```

If your php doesn't support `array_combine` use a loop to initialize `$dummy`:

```
foreach($a[0] as $k => $_)
    $dummy[$k] = 0;
```

Finally, to calculate a union of keys from all subarrays instead of using first item's keys, init `$dummy` like this:

```
foreach($a as $v)
    foreach($v as $k => $_)
        $dummy[$k] = 0;
```

Comment: `$v += $dummy;` same like `array_merge($v,$dummy)`?

Comment: @UnskilledFreak: rather like `array_merge($dummy, $v)`.

Answer (score 0):

So as I said get all keys from array A:

```
$keys = array_keys($array['A']);
```

$keys is now an array with all they keys.
Now the only thing you need todo is loop over your entire array and loop over the keys tocheck if they exists..

```
foreach($array as &$arr){
    foreach($keys as $key){
        if(!array_key_exists($key, $arr)){
            $arr[$key] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```